# How to unwrap a &Result<_,_>?

Tags: rust

What is a good way to extract data from a `&Result` type?

In my specific case, I have a `&Result<DirEntry, Error>` type, which I can't unwrap because I don't own the object. I tried to dereference and clone it `(*left_item).clone()`, but that just gives me a error with the note:

```
the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`std::result::Result<std::fs::DirEntry, std::io::Error> : std::clone::Clone`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [`Result::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_ref):

> Converts from `Result<T, E>` to `Result<&T, &E>`.
>
> Produces a new `Result`, containing a reference into the original, leaving the original in place.

The following code solves your problem:

```
let entry: &DirEntry = result.as_ref().unwrap();
```

For a mutable version, [`Result::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_mut) is provided.