# How to borrow an unwrapped Option<T>?

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

I want to iterate over a vector using `.iter_mut()` and `.map()`:

```
fn calculate_distances(planes : &mut Vec<Aeroplane>, x: f64, y: f64) {
    fn calculate_distance(x1: &f64, y1: &f64, x2: &f64, y2: &f64) -> f6 { ... }
    planes.iter_mut().map(|a| if a.position.is_some() {
        let pos: &Position = &a.position.unwrap();
        a.distance = Some(calculate_distance(&x, &y, &pos.latitude, &pos.longitude));
    });
}
```

`Aeroplane` contains instance of my `Position` struct:

```
struct Position {
    latitude: f64,
    longitude: f64,
}
```

In my understanding I'm just borrowing the position information not moving out anything, but the borrow-checker refuses my code:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
   --> src/main.rs:145:31
    |
  4 |         let pos: &Position = &a.position.unwrap();
    |                               ^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The `unwrap` call is going to move data out of the `Option` you're borrowing. You should interject an `Option::as_ref`, which turns an `&Option<T>` into an `Option<&T>`, this way you can unwrap the option and still only be borrowing the data. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref):

> Converts from `Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`.

The following code solves your problem:

```
let pos = a.position.as_ref().unwrap();
```

For a mutable version, [`Option::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) is provided.

Your code does not work, because as [stated by turbulencetoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385381/how-to-borrow-an-unwrapped-optiont/51386397#comment89743020_51385381) you try to move the data out of the `Option` and borrow the moved data.

However, in this case the better solution would be [if let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/if-let.html):

```
if let Some(ref pos) = a.position {
    a.distance = Some(calculate_distance(&x, &y, &pos.latitude, &pos.longitude));
}
```

---

See also:

- [How do I borrow a reference to what is inside an Option<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282117/how-do-i-borrow-a-reference-to-what-is-inside-an-optiont)
- [How to unwrap a &Result<_,_>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482210/how-to-unwrap-a-result/50482322#50482322)