# How to convert Option<T> to Option<&T> in the most idiomatic way in Rust?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a value `x` that has the type of `Option<T>`, how do I convert it to `Option<&T>` ?
I tried using `map`:

```rs
let result = x.map(|x| &x)
                       ^^ Error
```

But I got the error:

```
cannot return reference to function parameter `x`
returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

Comment: Related: [How to borrow an unwrapped Option<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385381/how-to-borrow-an-unwrapped-optiont)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot move out of value which is behind a shared reference when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338659/cannot-move-out-of-value-which-is-behind-a-shared-reference-when-unwrapping)

Comment: @pretzelhammer No it does not, although the solution looks similar, I believe it's a totally different question. I'm specifically asking how to convert Option<T> to Option<&T>, even the error thrown is phrased differently. Therefore I request that this question to be opened again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the method, which is `as_ref`.

Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref